# Add non existing data in datatable to database without deleting the existing data

Tags: c#, sql

I have a datatable, example data is like this:
[image].

I need to add other data like this:

[image].

How can I add that new data from datatable to database without deleting the existing data?
Here is my example code but this code saves all data in the datatable, that's why it creates duplicate data in database.

```
if (dtEmailAddress.Rows.Count>0)
        {
            string strDBConfig = Application.StartupPath + @"\MedXPro.xml";
            string sql = "INSERT INTO AgencyEmailAddress (AgencyID, EmailAddress) VALUES (@AgencyID, @EmailAddress)";
            using (SqlConnection conn = PSCSClass.DataConnections.MDFConnection("", "", false, "", "", strDBConfig))
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dtEmailAddress.Rows)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgencyID", row["AgencyID"]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", row["EmailAddress"]);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            dtEmailAddress.Rows.Clear();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to check for existence, and update or create in a single SQL statement. Just something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE dbo.AgencyEmailAddress SET EmailAddress WHERE AgencyID = @agencyId;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
  INSERT dbo.AgencyEmailAddress(AgencyID, EmailAddress) 
      SELECT @agencyId, @emailAddress;
END
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Since doing this from C# code may be very inconvenient, I would create a procedure `UpdateAgency` and call it from C#.

Comment: Hi Sir, when I try this code it runs but no change in database, here's my code.

Comment: SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("saveEmail", sqlcnn);
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@agencyID", row["AgencyID"]));
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@emailAddress", row["EmailAddress"]));
                        sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@@ROWCOUNT", dtEmailAddress.Rows.Count));
                        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 0):

**I UPDATED MY ANSWER AFTER RE-READING THE QUESTION**
Sorry I misunderstood the initial problem

You can check for the existence of the data in the same query like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AgencyEmailAddress WHERE EmailAddress = @EmailAddress)

    INSERT INTO AgencyEmailAddress (AgencyID, EmailAddress) VALUES (@AgencyID, @EmailAddress)
```

Comment: it gives me an error Sir. sorry i am just beginner in C#

Comment: Yes. 
Basically checks to see if the value is in the DB, if not, it runs an INSERT

Comment: the name "NOT" does not exist in the current context